# Where should I put `header` and `data` in Http_client.Convenience.http_post?

Tags: ocaml

OCamlnet 3 has `Http_client.Convenience.http_post`.

Its API is like this:

> val http_post : string -> (string * string) list -> string
>
> Does a "POST" request with the given URL and returns the response
>   body. The list contains the parameters send with the POST request.

**My question is::**

where should I supply the header and data body for the `post request`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIR you can not provide custom header in *Convenience* method. However, you can always use the *pipeline* API:

```
let _ =
    let call = new Http_client.post
        "http://localhost:8080"
        [("param", "value")]
    in
    call#set_req_header "User-Agent" "Foozilla 1.0";
    call#set_req_header "Myheader" "foo";
    let pipeline = new Http_client.pipeline in
    pipeline#add call;
    pipeline#run ();
```